# Why Does a Lot of Pastry Have an Orange Flavor?

Tags: pastry

At several different bakeries I've gone to over time, I have gotten pastries from danishes to cinnamon rolls and so on.  Sometimes those pastries (the pastry dough itself) have had a slight orange flavor, even though the pastry wouldn't have an orange taste based on its name/description.

Is there some tradition or reason that I've come across this or is it some property of a common pastry dough recipe/ingredient?

Comment: Are you sure it's *orange*, and not just vaguely citrus? Ascorbic acid is a fairly common ingredient in commercial pastries. I've never been able to taste it, but maybe some people are more sensitive.

Comment: Perhaps it's the ascorbic acid.  I'll have to ask next time I'm at one of the cafes.

Answer (score 1):

Coriander perhaps; or, orange residue (by-product of orange juice production) often found in cake mixes, etc.

Comment: Good call on the cake mix residue.  Since the bakery obviously is making lots of cakes, too, that could be it.